Insert Data from one Table to Another with WHERE conditions
I have two tables
Table A has two columns I need to use and Table B has numerous columns I need to Populate with common information
INSERT INTO gs_object_sensors(imei)  SELECT imei FROM gs_user_objects WHERE user_id = '14'
The above code works and inserts the IMEI number based on the WHERE clause. What I need is to incorporate the above into the following INSERT command
INSERT INTO table_name (imei, name, description, ...) VALUES (*IMEI*, Disconnect, Battery Disconnect, ...);
On the above sql statement I need the IMEI from the first SQL statement with the additional name and description to be added to Table B. The imei is the row information from Table A and the user_id is also from Table A just being used for the WHERE clause. Name and Description will be a constant not found in Table A
INSERT INTO gs_object_sensors(imei)  SELECT imei FROM gs_user_objects WHERE user_id = '14'
I used this code and inserts the required information from Table A but need to add additional constant information to Table B

@nabinsademba this works great, thanks. Is there a way I can add INNER JOIN into this in bring in a 3rd Table C?

yes you can do the innerjoin afte WHERE using 'INNER JOIN'

Please provide both sample input data and the expected result as tables in your question, see also How to make a good example Furthermore, don't misuse comments to change your question or to raise further questions. Only ask one question at once. Edit your question if you missed some required information.

@nabin sademba Is there any reason you are posting as comment rather than an answer?

'Name and Description will be a constant not found in Table A' - where are these coming from then? Please add a worked example.

example QUERY to resolve the issue:
INSERT INTO gs_object_sensors (imei, name, description, status)
SELECT imei, 'Disconnect', 'Battery Disconnect', 'Inactive' 
FROM gs_user_objects 
WHERE user_id = '14';

where the data in quotes 'Disconnect', 'Battery Disconnect', 'Inactive' are additional constants that can be inserted to the Table B.
